# Intersection of Cartesian Products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \cap (B \times C) = (A \cap B) \times (A \cap C)$? 


The corollary to cartesian product of intersections is $(A\times B) \cap (B\times A) = (A \cap B) \times (B \cap A)$, but it seems like it should not be applied in this case


Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens when $A=B=C=\{0\}$?

Comment: Exercise for you: find three sets $A,B,C$ such that $A\cap(B\times C)\ne \emptyset$ and $(A\cap B)\times (A\cap C)\ne \emptyset$ simultaneously.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equation $$A\cap(B\times C)=(A\cap B)\times(A\cap C).\tag{1}$$

The left-hand side of $(1)$ is the set of all ordered pairs $\langle x,y\rangle\in A$ such that $x\in B$ and $y\in C.$ If $A$ doesn't have any ordered pairs, at all, then this is simply the empty set. However, if $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ are both non-empty, then the right-hand side of $(1)$ cannot be the empty set. To give a specific example, consider $A=B=C=\{\emptyset\}.$ Hence, the equation doesn't hold in general.

What you *can* say is that $$(A\times A)\cap(B\times C)=(A\cap B)\times(A\cap C).\tag{2}$$ Thus, the equation $(1)$ holds for all sets $B$ and $C$ precisely when $A$ is a set such that $$A=A\times A.\tag{3}$$ In particular, $A=\emptyset$ works, but no other finite $A$ will work, since in such cases, $A\times A$ necessarily has a greater cardinality that $A.$ I'm not familiar with any infinite sets $A$ that satisfy $(3)$.

**Edit**: By the Axiom of Regularity, the *only* set $A$ satisfying $(3)$ is $A=\emptyset.$ To see why, suppose by way of contradiction that there is some $a_0\in A=A\times A.$ Then $a_0=\langle a_1,b_1\rangle$ for some $a_1,b_1\in A.$ Put another way, $a_0=\bigl\{\{a_1\},\{a_1,b_1\}\bigr\},$ using the typical definition of ordered pair. Moreover, $a_1$ is the unique element $a\in A$ for which $a_0=\langle a,b\rangle$ for some $b\in A.$ Then we have $a_1\in\{a_1\}\in a_0.$ However, given $a_n\in A=A\times A,$ we similarly have there exists $a_{n+1}\in\{a_{n+1}\}\in a_n$ for some unique $a_{n+1}\in A.$ This gives us an infinite sequence of sets $$a_0\ni\{a_1\}\ni a_1\ni\{a_2\}\ni a_2\ni\cdots.$$ Letting $$X=\{a_n:n\ge 0\}\cup\bigl\{\{a_n\}:n\ge 1\bigr\},$$ we have that $X$ is a non-empty set, but that no element of $X$ is disjoint from $X,$ contradicting the Axiom of Regularity.

Thus, $(1)$ holds for all $B$ and $C$ if and only if $A$ is empty.

However, there are particular examples of non-empty $A,B,C$ for which $(1)$ holds.  For instance, consider $A=\bigl\{\emptyset,x,\langle x,x\rangle\bigr\},$ and $B=\{x,y\},$ and $C=\{x,z\},$ for some non-empty sets $x,y,z,$ none of which is has two elements (and so none of which can be an ordered pair). Then the left-hand side of $(1)$ is clearly $\bigl\{\langle x,x\rangle\bigr\},$ as is the right-hand side of $(1).$